# using C++ priority_queue comparator correctly

Tags: c++, comparator, priority-queue

This question was asked in an interview recently

```
public interface PointsOnAPlane {

/**
 * Stores a given point in an internal data structure
 */
void addPoint(Point point);

/**
 * For given 'center' point returns a subset of 'm' stored points that are
 * closer to the center than others.
 *
 * E.g. Stored: (0, 1) (0, 2) (0, 3) (0, 4) (0, 5)
 *
 * findNearest(new Point(0, 0), 3) -> (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)
 */
vector<Point> findNearest(vector<Point> points, Point center, int m);

}
```

This is following approach I used

1) Create a max heap priority_queue to store the closest points
`priority_queue<Point,vector<Point>,comp> pq;`

2) Iterate the points vector and push a point if priority queue size < m

3) If size == m then compare the queue top with current point and pop if necessary

```
for(int i=0;i<points.size();i++)
{
    if(pq.size() < m)
    {
       pq.push(points[i]);
    } 
    else
    {
       if(compareDistance(points[i],pq.top(),center))
       {
         pq.pop();
         pq.push(points[i]);
       }
    }
}
```

4) Finally put the contents of priority queue in a vector and return.

How should I write the comp and the compareDistance comparator which will allow me to store m points initially and then compare the current point with the one on top?

Comment: Share an idea.We could use space division like Quadruple tree or Grid.So when the center change, we don't need resort points or rebuild priority_queue.

Comment: why do you need priority queue? 1. measure distances to all the points. store distance-point (or point index) to a vector, 2 partial_sort  this vector 3. copy points to the result

Comment: `public interface ...` are you sure it's C++ ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach can be changed so that it uses the `priority_queue` in a different way. The code becomes a bit complex since there's an if-statement in the for loop, and this if-statement controls when to add to the `priority_queue`. Why not add all the points to the `priority_queue` first, and then pop out `m` points? Let the `priority_queue` do all the work.

The key to implementing the `findNearest` function using a `priority_queue` is to realize that the comparator can be a lambda that captures the center parameter. So you can do something like so:

```cpp
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Point { int x, y; };

constexpr int distance(const Point& l, const Point& r)
{
    return (l.x - r.x)*(l.x - r.x) + (l.y - r.y)*(l.y - r.y);
}

vector<Point> findNearest(const vector<Point>& points, Point center, int m)
{
    auto comparator = [center](const Point& l, const Point& r) {
        return distance(l, center) > distance(r, center);
    };

    priority_queue<Point, vector<Point>, decltype(comparator)> pq(comparator);

    for (auto&& p : points) {
        pq.emplace(p);
    }

    vector<Point> result;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        result.push_back(pq.top());
        pq.pop();
    }

    return result;
}
```

In an interview setting it's also good to talk about the flaws in the algorithm.

- This implementation runs in `O(nlogn)`. There's going to be a clever algorithm that will beat this run time, especially since you only need the closest `m` points.
- It uses `O(n)` more space because of the queue, and we should be able to do better. What's really happening in this function is a sort, and sorts can be implemented in-place.
- Prone to integer overflow. A good idea would be use a template on the `Point` struct. You can also use a template to make the `points` container generic in the `findNearest` function. The container just has to support iteration.